# how can we add default parameters in model scope in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, scope, rails-activerecord, default

I have the following scope in my model.

```
class Referral < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :date_range, -> (start_date,end_date) { where("created_at <= ? AND created_at >= ?", start_date, end_date) }
end

calling like this :- Referral.date_range(Date.today,Date.today)
```

How can we change this scope so that it takes the current date as start date and end date,in case if we don't pass any parameters while calling.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby actually has [ranges](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj19cKX2dPnAhVkl4sKHRZdB40QFjADegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fruby-doc.org%2Fcore-2.5.1%2FRange.html&usg=AOvVaw2gv8qKNM9-2amE5C5u4Rhx). Use them.

```
class Referral < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.created_between(range = Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day)
    where(created_at: range)
  end
end
```

The thing that everybody forgets about `scope` is that its just syntactic sugar for creating class methods in a one-liner. Any arguments you add to the block/lambda will be arguments of the method.

But if your method takes arguments it probably does not fit in a decent length one-liner. Thus your should not be using `scope` in the first place. While you can write multi-line methods with scope it a completely pointless level of meta-programming since it takes the exact same number of lines and is less readable and cannot be detected by tools that cannot find dynamically generated methods.